# Getting text of html select in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
select.onchange = function() {
   this.value; 

}
```

It's easy to retrieve the value but now I need the text of the selected element. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry... put .value before my edit instead of .text by accident 8-)...)

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming "this" is the select element
if (this.selectedIndex >= 0) {
  this.options[this.selectedIndex].text = "some text";
}
```